# Windows 7 "Waiting for background program to close"

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium. When I shut down my computer why does the screen show this:

[image]

Before shutting down I'm close all programs.

Comment: There is some application that does not close gracefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Windows Seven Forum](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/79686-waiting-background-program-close.html):

> 1) **This is not a problem. It's actually a good thing because Windows
>   is waiting for programs to shut down and disk buffers to be flushed to
>   disk. If it didn't do that you'd be at nasty risk for data losses.**
>
> 2) Some programs do take a while to close off... they have to save
>   settings, close disk files, shut down network ports, release memory,
>   etc. This too is perfectly normal behaviour.
>
> Inside windows when you do a Shutdown every running program receives a
>   WM_CLOSE message which initiates program shutdown. Right after that
>   they receive a WM_POWER message telling them the system is about to
>   shut down... if the program needs more time, it can delay answering
>   the WM_POWER message and conduct it's business shutting down. When ALL
>   programs have answered the WM_POWER message the system shuts off.
>
> Really guys... **this isn't something you should be worried about...**

Comment: I am a little uncomfortable when having to wait, is there anything I can do to pass this message, probably in the control panel or through other, please give me a solution, and if I click "Force shutdown", is it harmful?
Many thank's for your solution ..

Comment: If you click on "Force shutdown" it could be harmful for the programs that Windows are waiting to close, I mean, if you have a .doc opened on MS Word and yor Windows is waiting to this program to save your work on the disk, so you could suffer from the fact that your work will be lost. Another harmful point would be with programs that have a lot of used space on your system memmory or cache, if you don't wait to it close by itself, it would corrupt some cached file on your disk or even on your partition table. I reccomend you to always wait and let OS make it's work(unless it taking too long).

Comment: What's the rush?  How long do you typically have to wait?  If it's excessive that might point to another issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Close programs running in the background in Windows**

How do I reduce the number of programs that run in the background in Windows?
Closing programs running in the background on your computer can free up system resources for your other programs. This can resolve problems where your system is running slowly or two programs are trying to use the same device. It can also help you determine if there is a conflict with third-party software that's running on your system.

Solution 1: Temporarily disable background programs (short version).

Right-click the program's icon in the system tray (next to the clock), and choose Close, Exit, or Disable.

Solution 2: Temporarily disable background programs on Windows from Task Manager.

The Windows Task Manager can close programs that the system tray cannot.

Warning: If you use the End Process feature to close a program, you will lose any unsaved data in that program. Avoid ending system processes if possible, and be cautious when terminating system processes: you may disable necessary components of your system. You may need to restart your computer to restore full functionality.

If you are unfamiliar with the listed processes, follow these rules:

- Do not end EXPLORER.EXE, or anything with SYSTEM, SYSTRAY, or SERVICE in its user name.
- If you are unsure what a process does, do not end it.

If you end a required process by mistake, restart your computer, and the system should re-enable it.

If you are still having memory or device problems, choose the method for your computer's operating system:

Windows XP, Vista, or 7:
1. Press and hold the CTRL and ALT keys, and then press the DELETE key. The Windows Security window appears.
2. From the Windows Security window, click Task Manager or Start Task Manager. The Windows Task Manager opens.
3. From the Windows Task Manager, open the Applications tab. From the Applications tab, highlight each application you want to close and then click End Task.
4. Now open the Processes tab. For each program you want to close, highlight it/click it once and then click End Process. Donot  close System or EXPLORER.EXE.*

Answer (score 0):

There will always be some programs / services running in the background. You could either wait for the OS to shut them down on its own or hunt down and kill every candidate yourself.

I would rather wait a few seconds and the problem will vanish.

Comment: What happens if I click "Force Shutdown", whether it is harmful to the system?
Thank's for your answer ..

Comment: the OS first asks the processes "gently" to finish (aka store important stuff to disk, free resources etc). thats why it shows you the screen you have posted. it waits for a while and then it kills the processes "the hard way". all kind of "bad things" might happen there. thats what you trigger when you "force shutdown". again ... "might". it depends on the programs. eg, if you have a roboter lifting somewhat heavy and has it in a dangerous position .. you might want the robotor to let down the heavy stuff put to the ground very gently.