# WIN Task Scheduler - Wait before shutdown

Tags: windows, shutdown, hibernate, task-scheduler, wait

I have a laptop which performs a task scheduled by Windows task scheduler every 30 min. It is running in the background in the "hidden" mode. It takes about 2-3 min for task to finish.
If I then prompt to shutdown or hibernate while the task is running, is it possible to make it so that Windows waits before the task's full completion?

Comment: So you actually need [this](http://superuser.com/questions/427917/windows-7-waiting-for-background-program-to-close)... :))

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding windows gives applications/processes or running tasks 2 seconds before it cuts the lights out. Windows sends a command that the program or scheduled task may or may not understand. This being said it may give you the option to keep it running but if not you may want to find a better way to run what you need it to do. You could however keep the task running every 30 minutes and when the computer is shut down or turned on you could setup a start up and shutdown script.

**Referenced here**.

For **Startup/Shutdown:**

Run gpedit.msc (Local Policies)
**Computer** Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> **Startup** or **Shutdown** -> Properties -> Add
For **Logon/Logoff**:

Run gpedit.msc (Local Policies)
**User** Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> **Logon** or **Logoff** -> Properties -> Add

Hope this is helpful.